# Hashtags, How to replace text in a string with a link/route

Tags: javascript, html, string, meteor, hashtag

How do I replace a bit of text (that looks similar to this #tag") in a string with a link/route. I am trying to make a Twitter or Instagram like hash-tagging system. I know how to find the text I want to be the tag and check if it is a already a tag and create one if its not and make the route, but I have no idea how to make a small amount of text in the post a link/route call. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example? Then it would be more clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok I just did add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
texts = "This is #tag!!!";
texts = texts.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://www.google.com/?q=$1' target='_blank'>$&</a>");
</script>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/t5moz67o/